# add 1 business day to date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a `Date` object in R and would like to add 1 business day to this date. If the result is a holiday, I would like the date to be incremented to the next non-holiday date. Let's assume I mean NYSE holidays. How can I do this?

Example:

```
mydate = as.Date("2013-12-24")
mydate + 1 #this is a holiday so I want this to roll over to the 26th instead
```

Comment: A holiday where?  The US has very different holidays than, say, China... I think you'll be hard pressed to find a package maintainer that has compiled all of them.  However, making your own lookup table and jumping to the next day skipping Saturday and Sunday is feasible.

Comment: good point: just update the question to assume nyse holidays

Comment: Do you envision using a holiday table?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: I am not sure; that is one solution. I suspect there is a package that implements this functionality already potentially

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I might use a combo of `timeDate::nextBizDay()` and `roll=-Inf` to set up a `data.table` lookup calendar, like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(timeDate)

## Set up a calendar for 2013 & 2014
cal <- data.table(date=seq(from=as.Date("2013-01-01"), by=1, length=730),
                  key="date")    
cal2 <- copy(cal)
cal2[,nextBizDay:=date+1]
cal2 <- cal2[isBizday(as.timeDate(nextBizDay)),]
cal <- cal2[cal,,roll=-Inf]

## Check that it works
x <- as.Date("2013-12-21")+1:10
cal[J(x),]
#           date nextBizDay
#  1: 2013-12-22 2013-12-23
#  2: 2013-12-23 2013-12-24
#  3: 2013-12-24 2013-12-26
#  4: 2013-12-25 2013-12-26
#  5: 2013-12-26 2013-12-27
#  6: 2013-12-27 2013-12-30
#  7: 2013-12-28 2013-12-30
#  8: 2013-12-29 2013-12-30
#  9: 2013-12-30 2013-12-31
# 10: 2013-12-31 2014-01-01

## Or perhaps:

lu <- with(cal, setNames(nextBizDay, date))
lu[as.character(x[1:6])]
#   2013-12-22   2013-12-23   2013-12-24   2013-12-25   2013-12-26   2013-12-27 
# "2013-12-23" "2013-12-24" "2013-12-26" "2013-12-26" "2013-12-27" "2013-12-30"
```

Comment: I don't think you do not need a `data.table` for that.  A looping solution should do.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  I'm *sure* you don't need a `data.table` for that. It was really just the mentally nearest tool that I reached for when I wanted to roll back business days to dates having no subsequent business day (or however you want to describe that).

Comment: Very nice data.table tricks. Do you happen to have a corresponding version using dplyr and pipe %>%?

Comment: @KevinZhu Nope, I don't. Please feel free to post yours here in comments, though, if you construct a **dplyr** solution. I'll add it to the main post for others who prefer **dplyr**.

Answer (score 7):

Lubridate will not help you as it does not a notion of business days.

At least two packages do, and they both have a financial bent:

- [RQuantLib](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rquantlib.html) has exchange calendars for many exchanges (but it is a pretty large package)
- [timeDate](http://cran.r-project.org/package=timeDate) also has calendars

Both packages have decent documentation which will permit you to set this up from working examples.

A third option (for simple uses) is to just store a local calendar out a few years and use that.

Edit: Here is a quick RQuantLib example:

```
R> library(RQuantLib)
R> adjust(calendar="TARGET", dates=Sys.Date()+2:6, bdc = 0)
  2013-12-22   2013-12-23   2013-12-24   2013-12-25   2013-12-26 
"2013-12-23" "2013-12-23" "2013-12-24" "2013-12-27" "2013-12-27" 
R>
```

It just moves the given day (from argument `dates`) forward to the next biz day.

Answer (score 2):

`holidayNYSE(year = getRmetricsOptions("currentYear"))` also check out `isHoliday` from `timeDate` package