# Optimizing business-day check (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

My goal is to take a `startdate` observation from a data frame, compare it against a calendar, and if the date is not a business date (holiday or weekend), move push it back until it becomes a valid business day. I will do the same for `enddate`, but pushing it forward.

As an example, this is what my data looks like:

```
  tickers  startDate    endDate
1   GOOGL 2016-01-31 2016-02-02
2   GOOGL 2015-10-21 2015-10-23
3   GOOGL 2015-07-15 2015-07-17
4   GOOGL 2015-04-22 2015-04-24
5   GOOGL 2015-01-28 2015-01-30
6   GOOGL 2014-10-15 2014-10-17
```

And my calendar information:

```
        Date   Weekday Business         Event
1 2001-01-01    Monday    FALSE New Years Day
2 2001-01-02   Tuesday     TRUE          <NA>
3 2001-01-03 Wednesday     TRUE          <NA>
4 2001-01-04  Thursday     TRUE          <NA>
5 2001-01-05    Friday     TRUE          <NA>
6 2001-01-06  Saturday    FALSE          <NA>
```

So I'm achieving this the following way, with dplyr:

```
for(i in 1:10){
stocks1 <- stocks1 %>%
  mutate(startDate = as.Date(ifelse(startDate %in% dates[dates$Business==F,]$Date, startDate - 1, startDate))) %>%
  mutate(endDate = as.Date(ifelse(endDate %in% dates[dates$Business==F,]$Date, endDate + 1, endDate)))
}
```

I guess there must be a more elegant way to do this... Any ideas? Ideally with `dplyr` since I'm trying to master this package :)

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709654/add-1-business-day-to-date-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chron` package has some delightful functions called `is.weekend` and `is.holiday` which are very helpful here. As for optimization, this actually seems like the rare case where a `while` loop actually seems merited in R. You'll still need two, unless you want to do it very programmatically.

One caveat: `is.holiday` requires a list of holidays (by default it uses six American ones from 1992). We can just use the dates from the second data.frame where `Business == FALSE`, which may include weekends, but that's fine. Really, with this approach you could skip `is.weekend` entirely, if your weekend data is already good. In this case, the dates for the two don't align, so it's not terribly useful. Regardless, the approach will work with the right data. All together, where `df1` and `df2` are your first and second data.frames, respectively:

```
library(chron)
# make a vector of holidays in chron's dates form for is.holiday
holidays <- chron(dates. = as.character(df2$Date), format = 'y-m-d')
while(sum(is.weekend(df1$startDate) | is.holiday(df1$startDate, holidays)) > 0){
  indices <- is.weekend(df1$startDate) | is.holiday(df1$startDate, holidays)
  df1$startDate[indices] <- df1$startDate[indices] - 1
}
while(sum(is.weekend(df1$endDate) | is.holiday(df1$endDate, holidays)) > 0){
  indices <- is.weekend(df1$endDate) | is.holiday(df1$endDate, holidays)
  df1$endDate[indices] <- df1$endDate[indices] + 1
}
```

Alternately, you could build your own function with or without `chron`. `base` has a `weekday` function that does half the work, anyway. Wrapped in a function, you can easily chuck a function inside of `dplyr`'s `mutate`/`transmute`, so it will fit neatly into your chains.

---

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(tickers = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "GOOGL", class = "factor"), 
    startDate = structure(c(16831, 16729, 16631, 16547, 16463, 
    16358), class = "Date"), endDate = structure(c(16833, 16731, 
    16633, 16549, 16465, 16360), class = "Date")), .Names = c("tickers", 
    "startDate", "endDate"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(11323, 11324, 11325, 11326, 
    11327, 11328), class = "Date"), Weekday = structure(c(2L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Thursday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), Business = c(FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), Event = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("<NA>", "New_Years_Day"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
    "Weekday", "Business", "Event"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```