# Is there a way to use the round date to next trading day while keeping both date and variable columns in R?

Tags: r, date, bizdays

How can I round the dates in the date column to the following business day? So each Saturday, Sunday and holiday should be transformed to the following business day. Furthermore, how can we include the output from the other columns as well in the transformation to following business days?

I tried this with the bizdays function:

```
TestDates <- RawTweetDataWSentiment
View(TestDates)

bizdays.options$set(default.calendar="UnitedKingdom/ANBIMA")

cal <- create.calendar("UnitedKingdom/ANBIMA", holidays=holidaysANBIMA, weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"))

adjust.next(TestDates$Date, cal)

TestDates1 <- adjust.next(TestDates$Date, cal)
View(TestDates1)
```

This however only returns the date column

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709654/add-1-business-day-to-date-in-r Does this answer the question? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Jamie_B
I have tried to use the bizdays function which get the job done, but without including the additinal columns in the output with from my data set with my variables. 
I'll add my code to the original post/question.
I'll try to visit the link and see if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming TestDates is a data frame, try this, TestDates$new_dates <- adjust.next(TestDates$Date, cal) This is essentially adding a new column to the original dataframe

Comment: Thank you very much @Jamie_B! You saved my day